# Trouble installing Appcelerator Titanium modules

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I installed the ti.paint module ([link](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/807?1766624799#overview)) from the marketplace and installed the included demo app.  It works on Android, but I get a **"couldn't find module: ti.paint"** error on iOS.  Please help.

I should also note that I haven't been able to get ANY modules working with Titanium (not just ti.paint)

My Installation Steps

1. I downloaded it and and copied the zip file to the root of my project
2. I added the module to my tiapp.xml file and verified that it shows up in the
   modules section of the tiapp window (see attached screenshot)
3. I ran the app and it gives the aforementioned error in iOS, but works with Andoid

Note: to get ti.paint to run at all, I had to rename the folders 'Android' to 'android', and 'iPhone' to 'iphone'

Also: In a separate test, i installed the module by dragging the .zip file to the /Library/Application Support/Titanium folder and was met with the same error.

Finally, it appears as if the build process correctly processes the modules (in that it unzips it and creates appropriate folders), just doesn't recognize them when I include them in my app.js file.

This is quite urgent, please help.

Images:
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz14A.png

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include the module in the code, and not only in the tiapp.xml file.

```
var Paint = require('ti.paint');
```

From now on, you can call Paint.[functionName] to call the module.

Answer (score 0):

Your steps looks like correct. Still I would like to say:

1. Make clean your build folder and delete application instance from directory or simulator.
2. Make sure you are logged in to Titanium Studio with your Titanium Appcelerator A/C credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In Titanium Studio, try installing using Help > Install Mobile Module...